# Use of Tensor product to construct canonical map of Homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> > Let $V_1, V_2, W_1, W_2$ be finite dimensional vector spaces and $f: V_1 \to W_1$  and $g: V_2 \to W_2$ be linear maps.  Use the universal property of the tensor product to construct a canonical map
> >     $$ \psi : Hom(V_1, W_1) \otimes Hom (V_2, W_2) \to Hom (V_1 \otimes V_2, W_1 \otimes W_2) $$
> >     Show that $\psi$ is an isomorphism

The universal property of the tensor product is:

$$ if \; B: V \times W \to U \; is \; bilinear \; to \; U \Rightarrow \exists ! Linear \; map \; \beta: V \otimes W \to U \; s.t. \; B(v, w) = \beta ( v \otimes w) $$

A canonical map is a map that commutes.

$$ Hom(V_1, W_1) \otimes Hom (V_2, W_2) \to X $$

And

$$ X \to Hom (V_1 \otimes V_2, W_1 \otimes W_2) $$

Then what to do?  Is $X = V \times W$?  .. Sorry for so many edits, I hit the submit too early when wanting to preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to construct a bilinear map

$$ B \colon \mathrm{Hom}(V_1,W_1) \times \mathrm{Hom}(V_2,W_2) \rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(V_1 \otimes V_2, W_1 \otimes W_2) $$

and then use the universal property to obtain $\psi$. In order to define $B(f,g)$, you will want to use the universal property again. Instead of defining $B(f,g) \in \mathrm{Hom}(V_1 \otimes V_2, W_1 \otimes W_2)$, define a bilinear map $V_1 \times V_2 \rightarrow W_1 \otimes W_2$ by $(v_1,v_2) \mapsto f(v_1) \otimes g(v_2)$. Show that this is indeed bilinear and thus defines $B(f,g)$. Show that $B(f,g)$ is bilinear and thus defines $\psi$. Finally, use bases to check that $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Did you really mean $Hom(V_1 \otimes W_1, V_2 \otimes W_2)?$  If it should be $Hom(V_1 \otimes V_2, W_1 \otimes W_2)$

Comment: I don't understand your question because your latex is broken.

Comment: Yes sorry I will post that separate after fixing it

Comment: What I think the canonical map should be is:

$f \odot g: Hom(V_1, W_1) \times Hom(V_2, W_2) \to  Hom(V_1, W_1) \otimes Hom(V_2, W_2)$

$B: Hom(V_1, W_1) \times Hom(V_2, W_2) \to Hom(V_1 \otimes V_2, W_1 \otimes W_2)$

$\psi(f \odot g) = f \otimes g: Hom(V_1, W_1) \times Hom(V_2, W_2) \to Hom(V_1 \otimes V_2, W_1 \otimes W_2)$

Comment: No, that was a typo. Thanks for catching this up - I've edited my answer to fix that.

Comment: Omygosh awesome, Thank you @levap!